# How to show different contents before and after logged in (php)?

Tags: php, authentication, session

I want to show different contents before and after logged in to the site

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo "<li><a href='applications/employee/profile.php' class='top-nav-link'>Profile</a></li>
                      <li><a href='index.php?logout='1' class='top-nav-link'>Logout</a></li>";
}else if(isset($_SESSION['logout'])){
    echo "<li><a href='applications/employee/login.php' class='top-nav-link'>Login</a></li>
                      <li><a href='applications/employee/signup.php' class='top-nav-link'>Register</a></li>";
}
```

But this code is not directing to the index page with different contents when logging out

Answer (score 0):

Hello Adithya Nethmini,

Hope you are doing well and good.

Replace your code to below code :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    echo "<li>
            <a href='applications/employee/profile.php' class='top-nav-link'>Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='index.php?logout='1' class='top-nav-link'>Logout</a>
          </li>";
} else {
    echo "<li>
            <a href='applications/employee/login.php' class='top-nav-link'>Login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='applications/employee/signup.php' class='top-nav-link'>Register</a>
          </li>";
}
```

So, in above code you just need to check in session whether username is set or not. No need to check condition in else if.

Thank you,